# How do I focus on controls inside an asp.net table in the design view (VS2010)?

Tags: asp.net, controls, design-view

I created an asp table  in the markup view and inside the table row/cells.

I insert controls too.

It works fine.

When I go to the design view I and I point the table, I can't get to the controls inside the table,

How do I focus on the controls inside the table in the designer view?

Comment: Exactly the reason why I always work in code view...